# Displaying custom HTML or XML reports with Jenkins

Tags: xml, jenkins

I have generated custom XML reports through testing. is it possible to display these XML with Jenkins? If possible, then how to display it with Jenkins?

Comment: In every build u will b having workspace folder, which shows up in Jenkins gui. There u can have your xml reports. Is this what u r asking or did i got u wrong :D

Comment: I hope my answer in similar question can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64693159/2347210

Answer (score 4):

If it is a homebrewed XML, I would suggest that you first convert it to HTML then use the HTML Publisher Plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

Otherwise, mark it as a build artifact and allow users to download it from the Jenkins job.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to:

1. Configure listeners in your testNg.xml file.
2. Write the listeners classes.

Then, configure Jenkins to show the custom report after your builds:

1. Go to "Post-build Actions" -> Choose "publish html reports".
2. Add your directory where the custom report is, for example: /test-output
3. Add the index file under Index page[s], for example: custom-report.html

Run your build an see your custom html report on Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

Install HTMLPublisher plugin in Jenkins and after that perform the steps mentioned by Eyal

Answer (score 1):

There is this summary display plugin as well:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Summary+Display+Plugin

[image: Sample summary display from XML]

Answer (score 0):

[Badge](https://plugins.jenkins.io/badge/) plugin

Usage in a pipeline:

```
def icon = "info.gif"
createSummary(
  icon: icon,
  text: """<h1>My Custom Summary</h1>"""
)
```